# Rounding error in floating-point arithmetic

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754, rounding-error

There are several rounding modes in the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating-point arithmetic:

- Round to nearest: RN(x) is the floating-point number that is the closest to x.
- Round down: RD(x) is the largest floating-point number less than or equal to x.
- Round up: RD(x) is the smallest floating-point number greater than or equal to x.
- Round toward zero: RZ(x) is the closest floating-point number to x that is no greater in magnitude than x,

If a large absolute rounding error (close to the theoretical bound) is obtained when performing some computations with *rounding up*, does this mean that the error will be small if the same computations are performed with *rounding down*?

**I would like to clarify my question:**

Suppose we need to approximate the value of *x* using interval arithmetic with the floating-point bounds, i.e., compute the numbers *a* and *b* such that *a <= x <= b*.

Let, for instance, *x = x1+x2+...+xn*, where *x1,x2,…,xn* are finite positive floating-point numbers.

1. First, *a* is computed with rounding down: 
   *a=RD(x1+x2+...+xn)*.
2. Then, b is computed with rounding up:
   *b=RU(x1+x2+....+xn)*.

Next, suppose we know that

*x - a <= EPS,*

and also that

*b - x <= EPS,*

where *x* is the exact sum.

Which upper bound is valid for the length of the [*a, b*] interval: *b-a <= EPS* or *b-a <= **2**EPS*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose the exact mathematical result *x* falls between two finite representable values, *a* and *b*, with *a* < *b*. The least upper bound on the error is *b*−*a*. Let *e* be the error when rounding up (and hence *e* is *b*−*x*), and let it be nearly *b*−*a*. Then the error when rounding down is *b*−*a*−*e*, so it is small relative to *b*−*a*.

If *a* and *b* are not both finite, then either:

- *b* is +∞, and the error when rounding up is infinite while the error when rounding down is finite and hence comparatively small, or
- *a* is −∞, and the error when rounding up is finite while the error when rounding down is infinite.

In the last case, the error when rounding up cannot large in the sense you define, since it must be finite and hence cannot be close to the theoretical bound in this case, which is ∞. So no results that meet your prerequisite lie in this interval.

Comment: Thank you! That is, if x is the exact result, a is the result computed with rounding down, b is the result computed with rounding up, and it is known that |x – a| <= e and |x - b| <=e (i.e., e is the upper error bound for the directed roundings), then |b-a| <= e. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @KonstantinIsupov: As used in my answer, *e* is exactly the error that occurs when *x* is rounded up to *b*. Hence *e* equals *b* − *x*. It is not a bound on the error; it is the error.

Comment: I'm talking about another case. Let _EPS_ be the upper error bound for the directed roundings, i.e., it is known (theoretically) that _|x – a| <= EPS_ and _|x - b| <= EPS_, where _x_ is the exact result, _a_ is the result computed with rounding down, _b_ is the result computed with rounding up. What is the bound for _|b-a|: |b-a| <= EPS_ or _|b-a| <= 2EPS_ (only finite numbers are considered here)?

Comment: @KonstantinIsupov: *EPS* < *b* − *a*. One never moves more than the distance between the two neighboring values. Moving more than that, or even as much as that, would cross a representable value. But rounding always moves toward the nearest value in one direction or another; it does not go beyond a representable value. (In a directed rounding mode, where the direction is fixed, rounding moves less than *b* − *a*. In round-to-nearest mode, where we choose direction based on which way has a nearer representable value, rounding moves at most ½(*b* − *a*).)

Comment: How can I estimate the maximum difference between _b_ and _a_,  knowing that the following inequalities always hold: _|x-a|<=EPS_ and _|x-b|<=EPS_? Thanks!

Comment: @KonstantinIsupov: Do you know that the step between adjacent representable values, *b* − *a*, is not a constant? It depends on the magnitudes of the values. For 32-bit floating-point, the step to the next greater-magnitude value is 2^(floor(log2(|x|)-23)) (but at least 2^-149). For 64-bit, it is 2^(floor(log2(|x|)-52)) (but at least 2^-1074)

Comment: Yes, I know about it. In my previous comment, I assume that the step is already taken into account in the value of _EPS_. I added an update to my original post.